# I changed domains and post slug structure at the same time for my WP site. Can I use 1 redirect to do so with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am planning a domain change from example1.com to example2.com.  To add a twist to it, I also want to change my permalinks at the same time.  My current permalinks for posts have the date and I want to remove it.

I'm a bit hesitant to test and lose SEO so I was hoping someone could confirm this would work before.

Here is what I was thinking:
after changing domains I use this code in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/(.*) https://example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

then I found this rule to change dates:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ https://example2.com/$1
```

I saw this one as well:

```
RewriteRule  ^/(\d*)/(\d*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)$ https://example2.com/$4
```

I'm not sure what these rules specifically mean but I THINK I should be able to combine them like this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ http://example2.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

It doesn't seem quite right.

Or would simply changing the permalink structure in WordPress affect the change so that

```
https://www.example1.com/2019/01/how-to-write-about-cars/
redirects to
https://www.example2.com/how-to-write-about-cars/
```

**UPDATE**

Using MrWhite's answer below.  I added this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com [NC]
RewriteRule  ^/(\d*)/(\d*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)$ https://example2.com/$4
```

This is working now in the case of

```
https://www.example1.com/2019/01/how-to-write-about-cars/
which redirects to
https://www.example2.com/how-to-write-about-cars/
```

However

```
https://www.example2.com/2019/01/how-to-write-about-cars/
does NOT redirect to 
https://www.example2.com/how-to-write-about-cars/
```

It just returns a 404.  This likely isn’t an issue as nothing should be bookmarked but just in case, is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or would simply changing the permalink structure in WordPress affect the change

I don't believe this would implement the redirect from the old to new URL structure, if that is what you are thinking. (At least not by default.)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example1.com [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example1.com [NC]
> RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ http://example2.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
> ```

This looks OK. Although if the new URLs at `example2.com` don't contain the date (ie. `/YYYY/MM/` prefix) then there wouldn't seem to be any need to check the requested hostname.

This rule must also go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, before any of the existing WordPress directives (ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker).

You should first test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

#### Final Solution

This can, however, be tidied a bit. The following one-liner should be sufficient:

```
RewriteRule ^\d{4}/\d{2}/(.*) https://example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You do not need any of the `RewriteCond` directives. (Just the `RewriteEngine On` directive, if it doesn't already appear elsewhere in the `.htaccess` file.)

Note the `https` on the target URL. `\d` (shorthand character class) is the same as `[0-9]`. The trailing `$` on the regex is not required since regex is greedy by default. The `NC` flag is not required either, since there is nothing case specific in this regex.

---

*Aside:* (Don't use this!)

> I saw this one as well:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule  ^/(\d*)/(\d*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)$ https://example2.com/$4
> ```

This rule, however, is very wrong! Due to the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* this will never match in `.htaccess` and the rule will do nothing. But there are only 3 capturing groups in the regex, so the `$4` backreference would always be *empty* (everything would be redirected to the homepage, which would likely be treated as a soft-404 by search engines).

Comment: Thank you for this!  I'll try it out tomorrow.  One thing you said though "if the new url doesn't have dates".  If I change permalinks on the new domain to remove those dates (which is the plan) then would I need to do something different?  Google has indexed the old site with dates, so that's what I'm hoping to transfer through properly to the new domain)

Comment: @rudtek Yes, this is assuming you change the permalinks to remove the dates. In theory, only requests to `example1.com` will contain the dates. So if the date is in the URL then it must be for `example1.com`. (Although it doesn't matter if the request is for `example1.com` or `example2.com` - if the URL contains the date then remove it and redirect to `example2.com` at the same time.)

Comment: Perfect so tomorrow I'll change permalinks within WordPress and then add the 3 lines but modify the bottom.  I still need requests for the old domain to be sent to the new one.

Comment: Hi @mrwhite I believe this is almost working.  Could I trouble you one more time?  I updated the question with more info.

Comment: @rudtek NO!! Sorry for the exclamation, but the rule you've appeared to use is the "very wrong" rule that I copied from your question just to explain that it is wrong! That rule wouldn't do anything. (I'm assuming this rule is in your root `.htaccess` file?) And you should remove the `RewriteCond` directives entirely.

Comment: @rudtek I've updated my answer to make it more clear which is the solution you should be using. :) And always test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect (ie. change `R=301` to `R=302` whilst testing.)

Comment: @rudtek Although I'm curious... in your updated question you say that regarding the stated rule, "This is working now in the case of" - but that's not possible!? Maybe you are seeing a cached response?

Comment: Ha.  Sorry for the mis-paste there.  I used the correct rule you suggested.  it's working except for dates in example2.com domain.  I had to keep the RewriteCond though or the site wasn't redirecting from example1.com to example2.com

Comment: @rudtek "I had to keep the RewriteCond though or the site wasn't redirecting from example1.com to example2.com" - That doesn't make sense. The `RewriteCond` directive(s) _restrict_ the rule to `example1.com` only. By removing the `RewriteCond` directives it doesn't perform that check so it naturally applies the rule to _any_ hostname. (_Aside:_ Incidentally, those two `RewriteCond` directives can be reduced to one: eg. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1\.com [NC]` - and you should backslash-escape the literal dots.)

Comment: I need the rewriteCond to make sure anyone just going to example1.com is forwarded to example2.com.  so do i need to keep the 2 processes separate?  You're clearly a master and this so I am leaning on you I know, but I am terribly thankful.